# The HTML file dont hit the CSS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am beginner in express, js and node.js

I have followed lot of tutorials about express, and i dont understand why the index.html file dont call the corresponding CSS file:

my server.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/0', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root : __dirname });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
 })
```

my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
    <title>Pt02 Ch02 Exercise 200</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">Aidez-moi à arrêter de crier !</div>
    <div class="heading">Je veux rester en majuscules !</div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

my CSS file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,900i');
html, body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  background: #15DEA5;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

and the different folders of the project:

[image]

when i type `localhost:8081/0`, the result is not the right result, the CSS is not active.

What am i doing wrong? thanks for help

Comment: That `public \ css` folder name looks odd unless is a VSCode name thing, but try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) bind `public` folder to site root (`/`) so after that you need to include static files without `public` in path:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your CSS is under public/css ? and not public\css
I'm not an expert, but I think that must be the issue. The folder of the project is named public\css, while your stylesheet rel is connected to public/css.

**EDIT**
The user above told the right answer I guess, statics folders shall not be listed in the html